# Using and/or operators in powershell command

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want this query to only return enabled users who have a name matching "marketing" or "accounting". However, when I run this it's returning disabled users as well? What am I missing? From my research this is what I came up with but it's not working.

`Get-ADuser -filter {(Name -like "*marketing*") -or (Name -like "*accounting*") -and (Enabled -eq "true")} -Properties *`

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't have this module installed but it looks like you may need to group your filtering logic. Does it work if you enclose the two "-like" comparisons in parenthesis?  { ( (Name -like "*marketing*") -or (Name -like "*accounting*") ) -and (Enabled -eq "true) }

Comment: [1] you are using the invalid but partially supported _scriptblock_ format. that is known to have problems with anything other  than the simplest filters. the specification says the `-Filter` is a _string_, not a scriptblock. ///// [2] you logic does not group the items specifically ... does the `-or` work against the 2nd AND 3rd items or only the 2nd? try using an additional set of parens to group the 1st & 2nd tests.

Comment: `Get-ADuser -filter {(Name -like "*marketing*" -or Name -like "*accounting*" -and Enabled -eq "true")} -Properties *` I just removed parenthesis. If it works I'll post as answer. if -Filter is string like Lee says, this prob wont work.

Comment: Thank you all. Shadow your solution also would work!

Comment: @Braden shadow2020's solution has the same problem your original command has: the `-or` condition is not grouped together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Boolean logic in general, AND takes precedence over OR. In other words, AND operations are evaluated first, before OR.

So that command is really asking for accounts where either:

1. The name contains "marketing", or
2. The name contains "accounting" and is enabled

To get the results you want, you need to enclose the entire `-or` expression in parentheses to force it to evaluate it first, and leave the `-and` outside the parentheses:

```
Get-ADuser -Filter {(Name -like "*marketing*" -or Name -like "*accounting*") -and Enabled -eq "true"} -Properties *
```

As mentioned in the comments above, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) tells us that the `-Filter` parameter is technically a string. So if you give it a script block (`{ }`), PowerShell does some translation on it to convert it to a string. Sometimes that translation can go wrong, so you're often better off giving it the string it should be, which would look something like this:

```
Get-ADuser -Filter "(Name -like '*marketing*' -or Name -like '*accounting*') -and Enabled -eq 'true'" -Properties *
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Removing the script block was also a good idea.